# Arch - GRUB with dm-crypt LUKS on LVM

Tags: boot, grub, arch-linux, lvm, dm-crypt

The last time I had to install Arch was a year or so ago. Grub always gives me the most trouble but I prefer it over syslinux.

> **HOW CAN I GET GRUB TO RECOGNIZE MY ENCRYPTED VOLUME?**

I get the GRUB rescue menu.

I have narrowed it down to two possibilities:

**1.) Not recognizing the correct encrypted volume:**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX= cryptdevice=/dev/sdaX:label root=/dev/mapper/vg-root
```

The last time, I guessed at it and got it to work but I actually want to know if this is correct. I read the Arch wiki and I get so criss-cross-referenced that I am unsure.

**2.) Grub installed to the wrong folder in /boot**

This was something that happened previously and I just made several copies of the .img to several folders inside /boot

```
/boot

/boot/boot

/boot/grub

/boot/boot/arch

/boot/boot/grub
```

And just to clarify, the /etc/mkinitcpio.conf looks like this:

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect keymap keyboard encrypt lvm2 block filesystems fsck"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

## **Some of this may be inappropriate if you have a different setup than me**

And second it should be:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=cryptdevice=/dev/sdx:vg-name` (without the space, with a vg name and the root= should not be necessary).

Regarding grub being in the wrong folder; if you run these commands after fixing the typo in `/etc/default/grub` it should not matter if you have .img files elsewhere:

`grub-install --recheck --target=i386-pc /dev/sdx
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

where /dev/sdx is the hard drive where GRUB is/should be.